vlookup with formula calculated from lookup cell location
The data sheet has a default value for a bunch of different properties of the product with the primary being in IPS units as we are a US based company but we often have work from other countries and thus need to work with other units, this would be great if everyone actually just used standard metric but we often get variants such as bar, kpa, kg/cm^2, g/mm^2 etc, so we typically just copy and paste in the formula from the side but after that has been messed up enough we are where we are at now.
I would like to generate a list of formulas that can be pulled from another tab that has other stuff such as materials etc. What I would like to do is have cell E6 reference the list of alternate units and from there have it vlookup and return back the proper formula for the conversion, but I am unsure on how to make the formula not get analyzed from the table reference location and instead from the new home location. These formulas will be referenced in a few dozen locations over quite a few different units.


The simplest solution maybe to use a lookup table with the conversion factors. Here is an example with weights:

The formula in column C is:
=A2*VLOOKUP(B2,G$1:H$13,2)

